# Inheritance from base class with constructor with parameters

Tags: c#

I am getting an error on this code and I cannot figure out how to correct it.

```
  public Track(string sKind, string tName, string loc,
                        string cName, string aSeason,
                        int numPlayed, int numWins, int numPlayers)
        : base(sKind, tName, loc, cName, aSeason, numPlayed, numWins)
    {
        numOfPlayers = numPlayers;
    }
```

This is the error:

> CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'numPlayers' of 'Football.Football(string, string, string, string, string, int, int, int)' Track

I am passing the constructor with the am parameters as the base class.

Comment: `base()` has 8 parameters, you are passing just 7.

Comment: Are you getting that error on the line `: base(...`, or on the line where you instantiate `Track()`?

Comment: You should really consider refactoring your code to reduce the number of constructor arguments. Best practices suggest no more than 3

Comment: Yes it is coming from the   : base(...  line.

Answer (score 1):

Just add numPlayers to your call to the base constructor:

```
: base(sKind, tName, loc, cName, aSeason, numPlayed, numWins, numPlayers)
```

(Note that your base constructor needs 8 parameters (5 string/3 int), but you are only passing 7 (5 string/2 int)).

Comment: Thank you!!! That fixed it!